# Local notification every hour with Ionic Framework not working?

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, localnotification

I am trying to send a local notification every hour with Ionic Framework... It asked for permissions to sent a notification but I never got one on my iOS device.

```
var oneHourLater = new Date();
oneHourLater.setHours(oneHourLater.getHours() + 1)

var notification = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Reminder',
  text: 'Reminding you about a thing',
  every: 'hour',
  at: oneHourLater
};

localNotifications.schedule(notification);
```

If this is not too much to ask is there any way to also not send one after a certain time so it does not get too annoying and then start them up again at a certain time?

Thanks!

Comment: `new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() + 1))` Really...

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 What?

Comment: You created 3 new `Date` instances just to set the date one hour from now.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I guess that is a little much but I do not know how to do it any other way?

Comment: Like this: `var oneHourLater = new Date(); oneHourLater.setHours(oneHourLater.getHours() + 1);`

Comment: Thanks... still does not fix my problem but makes it neater i guess

Comment: I can't test your code because I don't have Ionic set up right now, but reading the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/) it seems like you can just omit `every: "hour"` so that it won't send another one every hour.

Comment: @arodebaugh what plugin you are using , because [this](https://github.com/acianti/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) plugin matches for the iOS 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting the Local Notification at every One hour can be achieved using [this](https://github.com/acianti/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) plugin as follows:

```
localNotifications.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title:'Reminder',
    text: "Reminder you about a thing",
    firstAt: After_1_hour,
    every: "hour" // "minute", "hour", "week", "month", "year"
});
```

For `After_1_hour` you can try the following:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(1);
today.setMinutes(0);
today.setSeconds(0);
var After_1_hour = new Date(today);
```